# glossaries-extra – usage of \ifglsused with acronyms loaded from external file causes error

Tags: glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I use `\ifglsused` command in my document. It works well as long as the entry it refers to is already used (e.g., when line `2. \ac{at}.\\` in MWE body is uncommented). However, if this entry has not been used in the document, the following error is returned by LaTeX:

> **l.27** Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifglo@at@flag' undefined.

Solutions like adding `\glsadd{at}` to the preamble or changing `\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries}]` to `\newacronym{ao}{AO}{acronym one}` and `\newacronym{at}{AT}{acronym two}` are not sufficient, because in such cases an unnecessary entry for (unused) `at` acronym entry would be added to the list of acronyms.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,acronym,shortcuts=ac]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{relsize}
\setabbreviationstyle[\acronymtype]{long-short-sm}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{entries.bib}
    @acronym{ao,
        long      = {acronym one},
        short     = {AO}
    }

    @acronym{at,
        long      = {acronym two},
        short     = {AT}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries}]

\begin{document}

    1. \ac{ao}.\\
%   2. \ac{at}.\\
    3. \ifglsused{at}{Acronym 2 has been used}{Acronym 2 has \emph{not} been used}.

    \printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

**Desired output file:**
[image: Desired result.]

Is it possible to obtain such result, i.e., to be able to use `\ifglsused{at}{…}{…}` even when there are no commands like `\ac{at}` in the document (but there still might be an entry for `at` in acronyms’ BIB source file for future usage)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is now fixed in version 1.33 of `glossaries-extra` (2018-07-26).

A patch for older versions is to redefine `\ifglsused` as follows:

```
\renewcommand*{\ifglsused}[3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#1}{\ifbool{glo@\glsdetoklabel{#1}@flag}{#2}{#3}}%
}
```

The base `glossaries` package just defines this command as:

```
\newcommand*{\ifglsused}[3]{%
  \ifbool{glo@\glsdetoklabel{#1}@flag}{#2}{#3}%
}
```

which relies on `\ifbool` to generate an error and do nothing if the supplied boolean variable doesn't exist.

Usually `glossaries` uses `\glsdoifexists` for cases that require the existence of the given entry. If the entry given by the label isn't defined this command triggers an error. The base `glossaries` package omits an extra check in `\ifglsused` as it can defer to `\ifbool`. (Although it doesn't make much of a saving omitting just one test in the code, `\ifglsused` is internally used many times, so it adds up, and there are users who complain about the build time when creating a document that uses the `glossaries` package.)

The `glossaries-extra` package provides the package option `undefaction=warn`, which changes the behaviour of `\glsdoifexists` to generate a warning instead of an error message and, if used in the `document` environment, ?? will be displayed in the text. This means that `\ifglsused` now does need an extra test to allow for this setting.

If only `\ifglsentryexists` is used (instead of `\glsdoifexists`) then you won't get any indication when something goes wrong. For example, if the label is misspelt or if `bib2gls` failed to select the entry. This is why the new version uses `\glsdoifexists` to make it consistent with the base package's behaviour. The purpose of `undefaction=warn` is to simply change errors to warnings and provide a visual indicator, without making any other modification. This mode was originally intended as way of working on draft documents with incomplete references. When `bib2gls` and the `record` were later introduced, the `undefaction=warn` option conveniently deals with the first LaTeX run where no entries are defined (because they're not defined until `bib2gls` creates the associated files).

Version 1.34 (2018-07-29)¹ provides `\GlsXtrIfUnusedOrUndefined{`*label*`}{`*true*`}{`*false*`}` which does *true* if either the entry given by *label* is undefined or if it hasn't been marked as used. This may be a better command for use with `bib2gls`.

Neither `\ifglsused` nor `\GlsXtrIfUnusedOrUndefined` should be used in a post-link hook to reference the associated entry's first use flag, as it will have already been unset by the time the hook is used. Instead you can use `\glsxtrifwasfirstuse`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[undefaction=warn]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-noshort}
\newabbreviation{ab}{AB}{Abbreviation}

\glsdefpostlink{abbreviation}{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{ (\glsps{\glslabel})}{}}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{ab}.
Next use: \gls{ab}.

\end{document}
```

[image: First use: Abbreviation (AB). Next use: Abbreviation.]

---

¹ Allow a few days for it to reach the TeX distributions.

Comment: Your patch will not output anything if the acronym  is not used. Imho the op is more looking for `\ifglsentryexists{#1}{\ifbool{glo@\glsdetoklabel{#1}@flag}{#2}{#3}}{#3}%`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's intentional and documented in the manual. The patch will produce ?? in the text, which is what all the `\gls` etc commands do when the entry isn't defined when used with the `record` option.

Comment: This is actually useful for me, as I define own command like `\newcommand*{\ace}[1]{\ifglsentryused{#1}{\acl{#1}}{\ac{#1}}}` that expands to "acronym two (AT)" on first use and to "acronym two" on subsequent ones. Here, `\ifglsentryused` might be defined as `\newcommand*` according to Ulrike Fischer's comment (I don't know if this is the best solution, but the effect is achieved). `\ifglsused` is probably more useful for other purposes, as basing `\ace` on it would return undesired "??" in case when only `\ace`'s are used in the document.

Comment: @Peter I'm sorry, I don't understand the purpose of your `\ace` command. Why not change the abbreviation style or use the post-link hook to achieve that effect with just `\ac`?

Comment: Normally I use the `\ac` command that gives “acronym two (AT)” on first use in a given chapter (using `\preto\chapter{\glsresetall}`) and just “AT” further with the chosen style. However, I would like to have a special command that uses the long version (i.e., “acronym two”, like `\acl`) everywhere to emphasize the meaning of the acronym. Additionally, when it is the first acronym use in a chapter, the short version should be appended to the long one (i.e., “acronym two (AT)” as in the first use of `\ac`). That is why I defined `\ace` that acts like `\ac` on first time and like `\acl` later.

Comment: As I wrote, I’m not sure whether it is the most effective/elegant way to achieve what I want, but I am probably not familiar enough with the package to reach this by using post-link hook. Would it have some advantages over the above approach? Maybe this is incorrect apprach to have special command like this, but sometimes I think that `\acl` would be more suitable to use and I don’t want to check if it is not the first instance in chapter to replace it with regular `\ac` to present the short version to the reader.